# Change View height programmatically Smoothly

Tags: android, view, height

I am trying to change the height of the view programmatically.
What i have tried is -

```
RelativeLayout rlOne;
rlOne = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rlOne);
```

And on some click event i am changing the height using the LayoutParams.

```
rlOne.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, NEWHEIGHT));
```

The height is increased but the transition is not smooth.
How can i achieve a smooth transition from view's original height to view's new height?
Can i slow down the transition ?

Comment: Why don't you just anmate the transition?

Comment: @MocialovBoris : Can u give me some more inputs on this. Shall i use the scale animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play with from/to/speed values

```
ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(from, to, from, to, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
rlOne.setAnimation(scaleAnimation);
```

Source:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/1624689/1276374

Comment: is there any thing except scale because if i scale  the textView from one side, it does not look decreasing width, it look like comprising

Answer (score 2):

Basically the idea is that, you calculate the new height (the height after your view increasing) view first and write an thread, increase the height of you old view (the height of your view before increasing) pixel by pixel(may be 5-10 pixels at a time) until it reaches the new height. Hope the idea could help.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a for loop, where the view's height is increased by very little, than a pause is made before increasing the counter. In this way, the user will have the impression of a smooth transition.

Answer (score -2):

Use

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: Doesn't compile, you're assigning a reference to an Object of type `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` to a variable of type `LinearLayout`.